# i'm trying to match up an int with a row and getting that row of data in tensorflow

Tags: pandas, csv, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I'm new to TensorFlow and I need to use it for an algorithm. I need it to match up an age with a row and fetch the data depending on the age and print it. how would I do this?(oh yea it's from a CSV btw)

Comment: Perhaps you can use Pandas to read the csv then Select the row using `df.loc`

Comment: @NanoBit I just got '95' from `dftrain.age.loc[20]` is this correct and if so what does 95 mean

Comment: Need more info. Give some examples on table structure, content, and expectations.

Comment: I completely redid the CSV. here is my use I want to sign up for a streaming service and when you first do you need recommendations for what to watch. and it takes in your gender and your age and gives you recommendations from that. however, what I don't know is how to locate the row and see what genres to recommend. here is the CSV  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mqiC3CK5m6fVSvjjGXR5zr1Zyu7ZDIX3w31gmJquIDg/export?format=csv

Comment: @NanoBit there it is

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loc` to get data from a certain condition.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df.loc[df['age'] == 5])
```

Output

```
   sex  age  kids  marveldc  sports  ...  action  documentries  sci fy  sitcom  thriller
0    0    5     1         1       0  ...       0             0       0       0         0
```

References:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html